# Update, select atomic. GORM ORM

Tags: go, go-gorm

Can I do something like this in gorm , psql?

```sql
UPDATE job SET status = 'RUNNING' WHERE status = 'PENDING' RETURNING *
```

I want to get all rows that were changed by the update with a single atomic operation. If there are other solutions please write it.

Comment: Not sure if that's even possible and I wouldn't complicate things that much. You have `RowsAffected` but that only returns the count of rows that have been updated. Also you can use [Transactions](http://gorm.io/docs/transactions.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible having only a little downside as far as I know

Assuming your model is called `Job`, you can do something like this...

```golang
var jobs []Job
db.Find(&jobs).Where("status = ?", StatusPending).Update("status", StatusRunning)
```

The lines affect will be in the `jobs var`, but I have to say that you will receive the lines how they were BEFORE the Update, so the status of the models will be 'PENDING'